# extendable map vector using structure of union

Tags: c, pointers, vector, struct

On beginning i have to apologize if i made 2nd topic instead of sticking to the first one but i'm new to stackoverflow.

I've asked in the previous question i had:
[Creating dynamic vector on predefined struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616103/creating-dynamic-vector-on-predefined-struct)

And received a lot of useable informations about the problem i've had. But the problem is still not quite transparent for me to solve it.

still working @ that structure:

```
typedef struct somestruct_s {
    int s;
    union {
        unsigned char *ptr;
        unsigned char l_ptr[sizeof(char *)];
    };
}somestruct_t;
```

Since my last question i've been coding and trying my best to find the solution. The problem got a lot clearer to me since then. The point of this program is to create an dynamic and extendable map, map that will be used for bit operations. The endpoint is a map on which we can set some bits like: set bit on 260 index of our map to 1. If map can fit in memory occupied by the pointer to the map, then we can place it there, and that the point of this union. Another problem is that if there is an question about the bit that doesn't fit inside the map there is no error. We simply answer, there is bit 0. So for example if we set 0 on bit place that does not fit inside that map we don't extend the map. Map extending should only take place under 1 circumstance "we need to set bit to 1" outside of map.

AnatolyS gave me a few ice breaking tips:

A function, that if i understand well, returns pointer or map based on size (s):

```
unsigned char* somestruct_get_bitmap(somestruct_t* ths) {
    if( sizeof(char*) > ths->s ) 
        return ths->ptr;
    return ths->l_ptr;
}
```

and a bit clarification on contructor/destructor:

```
unsigned char* somestruct_init(somestruct_t* ths, unsigned char* ptr) {
    ths->s = strlen(ptr) + 1;
    if( sizeof(char*) > ths->s )  {
       ths->ptr = strdup(ptr);
       return;
    }
    strcpy(ths->l_ptr, ptr);
}

unsigned char* somestruct_destroy(somestruct_t* ths) {
    if( sizeof(char*) > ths->s )  {
        free(ths->ptr);
        return;
    }
}
```

But i still don't see it clear enough. Especially i don't quite understand the constructor and how the memory realloc should look like under the circumstance of extending the map.
Or how to manipulate the pointer to set and get the values of the extendable map.

Sorry that i can't express that simpler but the information is limited. As is my knowledge ;)

Comment: You should edit the original question instead of asking again.

Comment: Please clarify if all the data needs do be allocated adjacently as one big chunk of data (for example if it represents pixels on a screen, or some other hardware memory representation), or if it is sufficient to just allocate various independent chunks of data for each index. The answer would depend a lot on which of those two cases that applies.

Comment: @luser droog, since now i will edit always, my mistake :/.

Comment: @Lundin as one big chunk of data, previously we've used a fixed length, now extandable.

Comment: I don't mean it so harshly, and it's only my own opinion. But asking a new question leaves the old one as dead weight. I've voted to close the old one as a duplicate of this one; it should forward the answers here.

Comment: I *do* like the question, though. If you don't have good answers after a week or so, I'll come back and offer a bounty. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do, you want a large chunk of adjacent bytes, of any kind of data, which you will use for bit manipulations and which will change its size dynamically.

In that case, it is not rocket science. I have absolutely no idea where all the clutter about strings and the confused union (which does *not* save any memory what-so-ever) is good for. The sizeof pointer code doesn't make any sense either.

Merely do something like this:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t* data;
  size_t   size;
} bitmap_t;


bool bitmap_create (bitmap_t* bm, size_t size)
{
  bm->size = size;
  bm->data = malloc(size);
  return bm->data != NULL;  // return false if allocation failed, otherwise true
}

void bitmap_delete (bitmap_t* bm)
{
  free(bm->data);
}

bool bitmap_resize (bitmap_t* bm, size_t new_size)
{
  bm->size = new_size;
  bm->data = realloc(new_size);
  return bm->data != NULL;
}

void bitmap_set_bit (bitmap_t* bm, size_t byte_n, uint8_t bit_n)
{
  if(byte_n >= bm->size || bit_n > 7)
  {
    halt_and_catch_fire();
  }

  bm->data[byte_n] |= 1u << bit_n;
}

void bitmap_clear_bit (bitmap_t* bm, size_t byte_n, uint8_t bit_n)
{
  if(byte_n >= bm->size || bit_n > 7)
  {
    halt_and_catch_fire();
  }

  bm->data[byte_n] &= ~(1u << bit_n);
}
```

Comment: @user2207495 Huh? No it doesn't, that's complete nonsense. Your current union works like this: _"Allocate room for a pointer, or alternatively allocate room for a pointer, in case the size of a pointer is not the same size as itself. Then give me the opportunity to access part of this pointer's bytes by invoking undefined behavior, so that my program may hopefully crash. On top of this, please give me extra padding bytes if possible, so that I may consume more memory because of my union."_ As you hopefully can tell, all of the above is nonsense.